# How to partition Hard drive on ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Dear fellows I am new to ubuntu.. I don't know how to partition my hard drive like it is on windows.. please guide me the whole procedure to solve this issue.. I will be thankful to you.

Comment: When installing ubuntu, it will do it automagically for you

Comment: @Joren No partitioning software is "automagic". They will not know what to do unless you tell them so. Always be careful when partitioning a disk.

Comment: You have to tell the installation software to partition your disc for you, which it will do "automagically".

Comment: You haven't said whether you want to keep your windows install so you can be dual-boot or wipe windows and have an Ubuntu-only machine. That's an important question!

Answer (score 2):

When installing Ubuntu, it will ask you if it needs to partition the drive for you. This would be the easiest way to proceed.

[image]

If you want to partition your drive manually, you will need at least two partitions:

- One (or more) Ext4 partition: This will be the location for the Ubuntu system itself. Make sure you set the mount point to `/` (root). [Official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning%20issues?action=show&redirect=Partitioning).
- One Swap partition: Used as virtual memory. Also used for storing your memory when going into hibernate mode. You should let the size of it depend on the size of your hard-disc and RAM. [Official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

To manage your partitions, you could use a tool like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), or the installation disc.

Answer (score 0):

Open dash and search for "disks". Select your harddisk in the list at the left and use options to the right. If you need more specific information, then you'll need to provide more specific information in your question.